# Solving $\sqrt{0.25xy^{-0.75}}=y^{0.25}+1$ for $y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there any way of solving for $y$ for the following identity?

$$\sqrt{0.25xy^{-0.75}}=y^{0.25}+1$$

Are there any tricks/tools to help with this problem? Alternatively, is it possible to approximate a function for $y$? I know that the implicit function theorem enables a local specification of a function for $y$ around some point, but are there any more general techniques?

Comment: The given equation is not a polynomial.  Substitute the given values for $c$ and $r$ into your equation, and edit your post to include the expression you get *only after* substituting the given values into the equation.  Note, you will be left with an equation with the variables $v$ and $b$.  Do you know $v$?  If not, then your goal will be to express the equation in the form $b = \text{some expression with $v$ in it.}$

Comment: @amWhy Yes that's my goal, to express b as a function of $v$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT.-Your  equation can be transformed into $$x=4y^{3/4}(y^{1/4}+1)^2$$ which can be noted as $f(y)=x$.

Define $g$ (using the same analytic expression that for $f$) by $$g(y)=4x^{3/4}(x^{1/4}+1)^2$$ and take the graphics of both functions.

These graphics, of $f$ and $g$, are such that they are symmetric respect to the first diagonal which show that $g$ is the inverse function of $f$.

Can you explain why?. Define for example $x=e^y$ and $y=e^x$ and you will see the same symmetry so you have again an example of functions such that one is the inverse of the other. Try to understand this.

Comment: Above is $y=g(x)=4x^{3/4}(x^{1/4}+1)^2$ instead of $g(y)=4x^{3/4}(x^{1/4}+1)^2$. It was a typo.